# JavaScript - cannot set property of undefined

Tags: javascript

**My code:**

```
var a = "1",
b = "hello",
c = { "100" : "some important data" },
d = {};

d[a]["greeting"] = b;
d[a]["data"] = c;

console.debug (d);
```

I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'greeting' of undefined.

I'm trying to do something similar to an associative array. Why isn't this working?

Comment: d[a] is undefined.  In essence d["1"] is undefined

Answer (score 240, accepted):

you never set `d[a]` to any value.

Because of this, `d[a]` evaluates to `undefined`, and you can't set properties on `undefined`.

If you add `d[a] = {}` right after `d = {}` things should work as expected.

Alternatively, you could use an object initializer:

```
d[a] = {
    greetings: b,
    data: c
};
```

Or you could set all the properties of `d` in an anonymous function instance:

```
d = new function () {
    this[a] = {
        greetings: b,
        data: c
    };
};
```

---

If you're in an environment that supports ES2015 features, you can use [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names):

```
d = {
  [a]: {
    greetings: b,
    data: c
  }
};
```

Comment: This does work. the pattern should be: d = { [a]: { greetings: b, data: c } }

Comment: @robertjewell, good point, I've updated to include the note about ES2015 notation.

Answer (score 42):

You have to set `d[a]` to either an associative array, or an object:

- `d[a] = [];`
- `d[a] = {};`

---

Without setting, this is what's happening:

`d[a] == undefined`, so you're doing `undefined['greeting']=b;` and by definition, undefined has no properties.  Thus, the error you received.

Comment: `array` or `object`.  JS doesn't have associative arrays, though  `Object` can act like one for limited uses.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher: absolutely correct and important to know, but by that level of thinking, JavaScript has no arrays; it only has objects

Comment: Not exactly.  There are aspects of associative arrays that are not true about Javacript objects that can trip up coders. (True associate arrays aren[t limited by requiring keys to be strings.  The presence of inherited predefined properties is another major difference.) On the other hand, Javascript arrays, while objects, act like one expects a numerical array to behave.   One is an aspect of functionality, while the other is internal implementation.

Answer (score 8):

The object stored at `d[a]` has not been set to anything.  Thus, `d[a]` evaluates to `undefined`.  You can't assign a property to `undefined` :).  You need to assign an object or array to `d[a]`:

```
d[a] = [];
d[a]["greeting"] = b;

console.debug(d);
```

Comment: Best to assign an object: `d[a] = {};` - using arrays with non-numeric keys tends to lead to problems down the line.

Answer (score 8):

In ES6 you can use the spread operator, if `d[a]` is undefined it will just ignore, but if it has content it will keep it

```
d[a] = { ...d[a], greeting: b, data: c };
```

The accepted answer will override anything in `d`, which is not the behaviour we would always want

Answer (score 5):

In javascript almost everything is an object, `null` and `undefined` are exception.

Instances of `Array` is an object. so you can set property of an array, for the same reason,you can't set property of a undefined, because its **NOT** an object

Answer (score 5):

i'd just do a simple check to see if d[a] exists and if not initialize it...

```
var a = "1",
    b = "hello",
    c = { "100" : "some important data" },
    d = {};

    if (d[a] === undefined) {
        d[a] = {}
    };
    d[a]["greeting"] = b;
    d[a]["data"] = c;

    console.debug (d);
```

Answer (score 2):

This occurs due to setting value to an object property without properly defining it's structure.

eg:  The following code will give such error, because we are assigning value to an array. That can't be possible.

```
let boatNames = [];
 boats.map(boat => {
    while( i < boats.length){
      boatNames[i].name = boat.boat.name;
      i++;
    }
  })
```

To make it work, before setting some value to a property  (`boatNames[i].name = boat.boat.name;`) make sure you define it first. like this...       `boatNames[i] = {};`

Answer (score 1):

> d = {} is an empty object right now.
>
> And d[a] is also an empty object.

It does not have any key values. So you should initialize the key values to this.

```
d[a] = {
greetings:'',
data:''
}
```