# Javascript - Cannot set property 'value' of undefined

Tags: javascript, properties, undefined

I am creating a Javascript cycle, that can be put in the program instead of writing

`document.entry.(a_ to z_).value=(ax to zx);`

My work so far :

```
    function param() {
var counter2 = "ax bx cx dx fx gx hx ix jx kx lx mx nx ox px qx rx sx tx ux vx wx xx yx zx";
var alph2=counter2.split(" ");
for (var i=0;i<26;i++){
counter2[i]=1;
}
var letters2 = ".a_ .b_ .c_ .d_ .e_ .f_ .g_ .h_ .i_ .j_ .k_ .l_ .m_ .n_ .o_ .p_ .q_ .r_ .s_ .t_ .u_ .v_ .w_ .x_ .y_ .z_ ";
var let2=letters2.split(" ");

var entry = document.getElementById("entry");
document.entry[let2[i]].value=alph2[i];
}
```

But Chrome apparently doesn't like the second to last line, saying it `cannot set value of undefined` - and "entry" is a form in the HTML.

I am a Javascript beginner, so thank you very much for your patience :-)

Comment: Maybe you want `document.forms.entry` then?

Comment: Do you have any idea what you're doing? Your variable `entry` tells us you don't, as `document.entry` has nothing to do with the variable, and seems like a strange way to access an element ?

Comment: adeneo : Quite frankly no, I don't really know what to do now, since I am a beginner. And because of that I was hoping for an explanation, not for a post telling me I am an dumbass ;-) Bergi : nope, that doesn't work

Comment: We can't all get what we hope for, sometimes reality bites us the in ass instead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript - cannot set property of undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7479520/javascript-cannot-set-property-of-undefined)

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> counter2[i]=1;
> ```

What is that supposed to do? `counter` is a primitive string, so this will have no effect at all.

> ```
> entry.(a_ to z_).value
>
> let2 = [".a_", ".b_", …]
> entry[let2[i]].value
> ```

If you're using bracket notation, you need to omit the dot from dot notation property access. It should only be the property names in the array:

```
let2 = ["a_", "b_", …]
```

Also, you are not looping over the `let2` array, but just accessing the `i`th value in it - where `i` has the value `26` still. Wrap the `for` loop around that.

---

Apart from that, you can generate successive letters easily with [`String.fromCharCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode), you do not need to list the entire alphabet in a string or an array. Better:

```
var els = document.forms.entry.elements;
for (var i=0; i<26; i++) {
    var chr = String.fromCharCode(97 + i),
        alph = chr + "x",
        lett = chr + "_";
    if (els[lett] != null)
        els[lett].value = alph;
}
```

Comment: thanks, but would you mind guiding me a little with the loop ? I am really just a beginner - thanks

Comment: Ehm, and what about the for loop, doing `counter2[i] = 1;` when `counter` is clearly a string? Then there's the `let2` array using `i`, but there is no `i` in that context, it's outside the loop, and the `entry` variable is just like every other thing in the question, it makes no sense. If you can figure out how that code was intended to work, you're really good!