# AngularJS "unexpected token [" initializing array of objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What is wrong with this:

```
  var a = "1";
  var b = {};
  var b[a] = 'test';
```

According to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7479520/javascript-cannot-set-property-of-undefined), the above is valid. But `var b[a] = 'test'` is generating this error in AngularJS (v1):

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [

Comment: Remove the `var` from the third line and it'll be the same as that question.

Comment: DOH! I  was staring right at it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This line:

```
var b[a] = 'test';
```

is not valid, because the characters `[` and `]` are not allowed in variable names.

If you are not wishing to declare a new variable on that line, but rather just assign a key/value pair to the object `b`, you can just remove the `var`:

```
b[a] = 'test'; //b now equals { "1": "test" }
```

Comment: Yep, I actually see stuff like this somewhat often among beginners. `var` is only required for declaring/"create" a _new variable_. While `b[a]` doesn't currently exist, it's not a variable; it's a property of an object belonging to the variable `b`. In the same manner, you don't need `var` when assigning a value to an existing var, e.g. `a = 2;`.