# Combining two arrays to form a nested javascript object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I want to create an object which looks like the below code:

```
MyObject ={
 "United Kingdom":{
    "primary":{ 

    },
    "secondary":{

    },
    "service":{

    },  
},

"France":{
    "primary":{


    },
    "secondary":{

    },
    "service":{

    },  
},
```

What I want to do is automatically generate the object from an array, so I have two arrays:

```
CountryList = ["United Kingdom", "France"]

MarketList = ["primary", "secondary", "service"]
```

I'm doing it through a for loop

```
for (var i = 0; i < CountryList.length; i++) {
  for(var p = 0; p < MarketList.length; p++)
      MyObject[CountryList[i]][MarketList[p]] = self;
}
```

However I'm getting an error:

```
Cannot set property 'primary' of undefined
```

Any ideas on where I am wrong? It functions fine when looping through the country list but when I want to nest the "Market" object inside I get a problem.

Thanks!

Comment: You have to create the property, before you can assign another property to that one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript - cannot set property of undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7479520/javascript-cannot-set-property-of-undefined)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an object before assigning a property to it

```
myObject[countryList[i]] = {};
```

Juist a hint, variables with capital letter and following small letters denotes classes or functions which can be used as constructor.

```js
var myObject = {},
    countryList = ["United Kingdom", "France"],
    marketList = ["primary", "secondary", "service"],
    i, p;

for (var i = 0; i < countryList.length; i++) {
    myObject[countryList[i]] = {};
    for (p = 0; p < marketList.length; p++) {
        myObject[countryList[i]][marketList[p]] = {};
    }
}

console.log(myObject);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a condition to test if `MyObject[]` is not undefined.

```
if (MyObject[CountryList[i]]) {
      MyObject[CountryList[i]][MarketList[p]] = self;      
}
```

I think, the error you mentionned will be no more.

Answer (score 0):

With ES6 you can use object destructuring to get two variables, and `reduce()` to create that object.

```js
var MyObject ={"United Kingdom":{"primary":{},"secondary":{},"service":{}},"France":{"primary":{},"secondary":{},"service":{}}}

var result = Object.keys(MyObject).reduce(function(r, e) {
  if (!r.CountryList || !r.MarketList) r.CountryList = [], r.MarketList = []
  r.MarketList = [...new Set(r.MarketList.concat(Object.keys(MyObject[e])))]
  r.CountryList.push(e)
  return r
}, {})

var {MarketList,CountryList} = result
console.log(MarketList)
console.log(CountryList)
```