# Creating Json object from array

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using below code I'm attempting to convert an array of variable length to an object where item at position i is object name and item at position i+1 is item value. For example :

```
arr = []; 
arr.push('a');
arr.push(1);
arr.push('b');
arr.push(2);
arr.push('c');
arr.push(3);

/* Want to create an object that is of type : */ 

var ob = {a:1 , b:2 , c:3}
console.log(ob)
```

Here is code I'm trying to achieve this with  :

```
var ob2 = {}

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    ob2.arr[i] = arr[i + 1]
    i = i + 1
}
```

But receive error :

```
(index):63 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined
    at window.onload ((index):63)
```

fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/wxkkjzm0/

```js
arr = []; 
arr.push('a');
arr.push(1);
arr.push('b');
arr.push(2);
arr.push('c');
arr.push(3);

/* Want to create an object that is of type : */ 

var ob = {a:1 , b:2 , c:3}

console.log(ob)

var ob2 = {}

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    ob2.arr[i] = arr[i + 1]
    i = i + 1
}

console.log(ob2);
```

arr & ob2 are defined which this error pertains to ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Array to Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215737/convert-array-to-object)

Comment: Why are you incrementing `i` twice?

Comment: Obviously to only iterate over every 2nd element of the array.

Comment: `ob2` has no property `arr` because you **just** defined it to `{}` but you are trying to reference properties on it with `ob2.arr[i]`

Comment: `arr` is literal in `obj.arr[i]`. You want to retrieve the value from the `arr[i]` (ie. dynamic), so you need square brackets: `ob2[arr[i]]`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript - cannot set property of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7479520/javascript-cannot-set-property-of-undefined)

Comment: `for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i = i + 2) ob2[arr[i]] = arr[i + 1]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could increment the index variable by `2`, because you need a pair for assignment a key/value pair.

```js
var array = ['a', 1, 'b', 2, 'c', 3],
    object = {},
    i

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i += 2) {
    object[array[i]] = array[i + 1];
}

console.log(object);
```

Answer (score 1):

As the error is trying to tell you, `ob2.arr` doesn't exist.

You probably want the property with that name, which would be

```
ob2[arr[i]]
```

Answer (score 0):

your error is with:

```
ob2.arr...
```

and there's no need to do:

```
i = i + 1
```

since you're incrementing `i` in the `for` loop delcration (`i++`)

you want:

```
ob2[arr[i]] = arr[i+1]
```

note that you will go out of bounds if you leave that as is so do:

```
for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; i+=2) {
   ob2[arr[i-1]] = arr[i]
}
```

Comment: He wants `i` to increase by two every iteration.

Comment: @connexo why? i do not think that is necessary

Comment: Run this code and you will find out. Will end up with `{a:1, 1:b, b:2, 2:c...}`

Comment: yup, i just edited the code example. my mistake. dont see the reason for downvote..

Comment: Well when code and answer are wrong what do you expect?

Answer (score 0):

Destructive while loop approach

```js
var arr = ['a', 1, 'b', 2, 'c', 3],
    ob={};

while(arr.length ){
  ob[arr.shift()] = arr.shift();
}

console.log(ob)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are sure that your paired value match index and index + 1, try this code:

```
arr = []; 
arr.push('a');
arr.push(1);
arr.push('b');
arr.push(2);
arr.push('c');
arr.push(3);

console.log(arr);

var ob2 = {};

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length/2; i++) {
    ob2[arr[i*2]] = arr[(i*2) + 1];
}

console.log(ob2);

// output : {a:1 , b:2 , c:3};
```

The key is to divide iteration length by 2, and for each index, use array value of that index as new index value for object, and multiply index by 2 and + the result by one to get array value for next index.