# WebpackError: Cannot set property 'emulateTransitionEnd' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, gatsby

I'm trying to use Bootstrap on GatsbyJs, but It keeps disapointing me.

Is there a real way to import bootstrap without this error? `WebpackError: Cannot set property 'emulateTransitionEnd' of undefined`.

The full error is the following:

```
  WebpackError: Cannot set property 'emulateTransitionEnd' of undefined

  - bootstrap.min.js:6
    ~/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js:6:2684

  - bootstrap.min.js:6
    ~/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js:6:2876

  - bootstrap.min.js:6 module.exports.data.site.siteMetadata.title
    ~/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js:6:16

  - bootstrap.min.js:6 Object.module.exports.data.site.siteMetadata.title
    ~/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js:6:236

  - index.js:16 Object.exports.__esModule
    src/layouts/index.js:16:1

  - index.js:3 Object.exports.__esModule
    .cache/layouts/index.js:3:3

  - sync-requires.js:6 Object.exports.__esModule
    .cache/sync-requires.js:6:35
```

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript - cannot set property of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7479520/javascript-cannot-set-property-of-undefined)

Answer (score 1):

The best option is to use [reactstrap](https://reactstrap.github.io/), It is well documented and its builded with the latest version of bootstrap. It has all the components.

Comment: Reactstrap is still using Bootsrap v3.

Comment: Is now using bootstrap 4