# Create Key Value Pair Array in For-Loop

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this response from my ajax

and this is my `configs.objects`

```
configs.objects    = ['Mexico','Brazil','Spain','Italy','USA'];
```

[image]

`(7) [19, 51, 40, 69, 15, 77, 40]`

I created a for-loop

```
var datasets = [];

for (i = 0; i < configs.objects.length; i++) {

    console.log(i);

    datasets[i]['borderWidth']      = 1;
    datasets[i]['hoverBorderWidth'] = 2;
    datasets[i]['hoverBorderColor'] = '#fff';
    datasets[i]['data']             = response[i];
    datasets[i]['label']            = configs.objects[i];


    // debugger;

}


console.log(datasets);
```

I kept getting

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'borderWidth' of undefined

[image]

Why ? Am I doing anything wrong ? I've been staring at this codes for the last 2 hours.

I can't tell why I kept getting that error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript - cannot set property of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7479520/javascript-cannot-set-property-of-undefined)

Answer (score 2):

`datasets` is an empty array with no elements, and you never add any. Simply ensure that the `i`th element is initialized as an object fist:

```
datasets[i] = {};
```

You could also restructure your code a bit and instead `push` object literals to `datasets` for the same result:

```
datasets.push({
    borderWidth: 1,
    hoverBorderWidth: 2,
    hoverBorderColor: #fff,
    data: response[i],
    label: configs.objects[i]
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Before you set values, you need to initialize it to an object first:

```js
datasets[i] = {};
datasets[i]['key'] = 'value';
```

Further reading: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer

Answer (score 1):

```js
var datasets = [];

for (i = 0; i < configs.objects.length; i++) {

    let obj = {}

    obj['borderWidth']      = 1;
    obj['hoverBorderWidth'] = 2;
    obj['hoverBorderColor'] = '#fff';
    obj['data']             = response[i];
    obj['label']            = configs.objects[i];

    datasets[i] = obj;


    // debugger;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because by using `datasets[i]` you're approaching it as if that object already exists to grab out of the array and modify; when you're really trying to store those values in that empty array as objects.

The way you handle that is to create a variable to store those properties into then push that object to your array which can look like this.

```
var datasets = [];

for(i = 0; i < configs.object.length; i++){
    var dataObject = {
        borderWidth: 1,
        hoverBorderWidth: 2,
        hoverBorderColor: '#fff',
        data: response[i],
        label: configs.objects[i]
    };

    datasets.push(dataObject);
}

console.log(datasets);
```

Now the `datasets` variable will have objects with those properties and values which you can now index into.