# Trying to upload multiple image file using Formidable in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, formidable

I am trying to upload multiple image file in node.js using [formidable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/formidable) so error is in accessing the path property of fields in formidable

here is my app.js code

```
app.post('/',(req,res)=>{
    const form = formidable({ multiples: true });
    form.keepExtensions = true;
    form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
      if (err) {
          return res.status(400).json({
              error: "Image could not be uploaded"
          });
      }
      // check for all fields
      const {noi} = fields 
      
      let user = new User(fields);
      console.log(noi)
      console.log(files.img[0])
      
      //console.log(files.img.path)

      // 1kb = 1000
      // 1mb = 1000000

      l = noi // noi -> number of images 
      var  i = 0
      // to checck the number of image file user want to upload
       for(i=0 ; i < l; i++ )
       {
         if (files.img) {
             // console.log("FILES PHOTO: ", files.photo);
             
             
             user.img[i].data = fs.readFileSync(files.img[i].path);
             user.img[i].contentType[i] = files.img[i].type;
         }
       }

      user.save((err, result) => {
          if (err) {
              return res.status(400).json({
                  error: errorHandler(err)
              });
          }
          res.json(result);
      });
  });
  
})
```

the output for console.log(files) is :

```
{
  img: [
    File {
      _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
      _eventsCount: 0,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      size: 7682,
      path: 'C:\\Users\\kushw\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\upload_106d6e0c756a00460b552208b5ac8004.jpeg',
      name: 'download.jpeg',
      type: 'image/jpeg',
      hash: null,
      lastModifiedDate: 2021-10-18T14:03:29.718Z,
      _writeStream: [WriteStream],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    File {
      _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
      _eventsCount: 0,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      size: 7571,
      path: 'C:\\Users\\kushw\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\upload_be8b426dec71c4ead1cd07ee2f97a03a.jpeg',
      name: 'download1.jpeg',
      type: 'image/jpeg',
      hash: null,
      lastModifiedDate: 2021-10-18T14:03:29.721Z,
      _writeStream: [WriteStream],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    }
  ]
}
```

the error I am getting is :

```
  user.img[i].data = fs.readFileSync(files.img[i].path);
                              ^

TypeError: Cannot set property 'data' of undefined
    at C:\Users\kushw\Desktop\check\app.js:55:31
    at IncomingForm.<anonymous> (C:\Users\kushw\Desktop\check\node_modules\formidable\lib\incoming_form.js:107:9)
    at IncomingForm.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at IncomingForm._maybeEnd (C:\Users\kushw\Desktop\check\node_modules\formidable\lib\incoming_form.js:557:8)
    at C:\Users\kushw\Desktop\check\node_modules\formidable\lib\incoming_form.js:238:12
    at C:\Users\kushw\Desktop\check\node_modules\formidable\lib\file.js:79:5     
    at WriteStream.onfinish (internal/streams/writable.js:689:5)
    at WriteStream.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at finish (internal/streams/writable.js:657:10)
    at finishMaybe (internal/streams/writable.js:644:9)
```

So what I understood is I need to access the path in img, I tried many ways but not able to read that property.

my model is :

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const userschema = new mongoose.Schema({
    noi: Number,
    
    img:[{
      data:Buffer,
    type:  String
  }] 
  });

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userschema);
```

thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7479520/javascript-cannot-set-property-of-undefined

Comment: Thanks, It showed some progress and got other type of error I changed that code to user.img[i] = {
                data : fs.readFileSync(files.img[i].path),
                type : files.img[i].type
             }  Error is : throw new CastError('string', value, this.path, null, this);
    ^

CastError: Cast to string failed for value "{
  data: <Buffer ff d8 ff e0 00 10 4a 46 49 46 00 01 01 00 00 01 00 01 00 00 ff db 00 84 00 0a 07 08 16 16 15 18 16 16 16 19 19 18 1a 1a 1c 1a 1a 1c 1a 1c 1e 19 25 1a ... 7632 more bytes>,

Comment: Thanks Problem resolves it was in Schema definition .